# Insert space between pairs of characters - sed

Tags: sed, awk

Another sed question! I have nucleotide data in pairs

```
1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 CT TT CT TT CT
```

split by spaces and I need to put a space into every pair, eg

```
1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 0 0 C T T T C T T T C T
```

I've tried `sed 's/[A-Z][A-Z]/ &/g'` and `sed 's/[A-Z][A-Z]/& /g'`

And both `A-Z` replaced with `..` and it never splits the pair as I'd like it to (it puts spaces before or after or splits every other pair or similar!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this will work for you, however it's not perfect!

```
echo "1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 CT TT CT TT CT" | \
  sed 's/\(\s[A-Z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g'
```

gives

```
1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 C T T T C T T T C T
```

`sed 's/\(\s[A-Z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g'` matches whitespace (`\s`) upper case character (`[A-Z]`), puts that in a group (`\(...\)`), and then matches upper case character and stores that in second group. Then this match is substituted by first group (`\1`) space second group (`\2`).

**NOTE:**
This fails when you have sequences that are longer than 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

An solution using `awk` which modifies only pairs of characters and might be more robust depending on your input data:

```
echo "1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 CT TT CT TT CT" | \
  awk '
    {
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if($i ~ /^[A-Z][A-Z]$/){ 
          $i=substr($i,1,1)" "substr($i,2,1)
        }
       }
     }
     1'
```

gives

```
1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 C T T T C T T T C T1
```

Comment: If you let the for loop run from 5 or 6 to `NF` (depending on the OPs needs), you would avoid the need for the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo '1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 CT TT CT TT CT' | 
sed ':a;s/\(\s\S\)\(\S\(\s\|$\)\)/\1 \2/g;ta'
1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 0 0 C T T T C T T T C T
```

This second method works but might provide false positives:

```
echo '1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 00 CT TT CT TT CT' | sed 's/\<\(.\)\(.\)\>/\1 \2/g'
1 Affx-14150122 0 75891 0 0 C T T T C T T T C T
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually easier in python than in awk:

```
echo caca | python -c 'import sys;\
for line in sys.stdin: print (" ".join(line))'
```

c a c a